# Openshift - connecting pods between projects

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm having problems with a pod (running Keycloak) connecting to a database pod in another openshift project, on the same cluster.

### Version Info

- OpenShift Master: v1.5.1+7b451fc
- Kubernetes Master: v1.5.2+43a9be4

## Problem

In the Keycloak pod, the error I am getting is:

```
01:29:20,245 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression 'jdbc:postgresql://${env.POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}:${env.POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT:5432}/${env.POSTGRES_DATABASE:keycloak}'"
```

**Troubleshooting**

I have tried the following:

I've tried pinging from a pod in another project.

```
ping timescaledb.my-data-service.svc
```

and

```
ping timescaledb.my-data-service.svc.cluster.local
```

In both cases I get the following error:

```
From gateway (xx.xxx.0.1) icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: If your OpenShift cluster has multi tenant SDN plugin (which is usually the case unless using oc cluster up or Minishift), you need to open up networking between projects. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#admin-guide-pod-network This needs to be setup by a cluster admin.

Answer (score 1):

Service is not pingable, since it's iptables-based and not a real ip. You can test the service with command like `curl $service:$port`

Comment: I just get `ping timescaledb.my.svc.cluster.local:5432 
ping: timescaledb.my.svc.cluster.local:5432: Name or service not known`

Comment: Ping try to resolve the ip of the name 'timescaledb.my.svc.cluster.local:5432', it doesn't exist of course.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. This time, using `curl`, I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: I think that means the service is reachable at least.